# Regex matching a string starting with a number greater than a particular number

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

i have a list of files names,and i have to select certain files based on their names..file names are as follows

```
20150827_5406006_Calls
20150826_5406006_Calls
20150825_5406006_Calls
20150824_5406006_Calls
20150823_5406006_Calls
20150822_5406006_Calls
20150821_5406006_Calls
20150820_5406006_Calls
20150819_5406006_Calls
20150818_5406006_Calls
```

now i want to select files whose names start with a number greater than `20150820`

so my expected results will be

```
20150827_5406006_Calls
20150826_5406006_Calls
20150825_5406006_Calls
20150824_5406006_Calls
20150823_5406006_Calls
20150822_5406006_Calls
20150821_5406006_Calls
```

i know,we can some how do it with the help of regex.but i am very new to this concept.so how can i do it ?

Comment: This is actually not a particularly good use for regex.  You're better off just parsing the date and filtering on that.

Comment: i cant.its a ready made program .iam only allowed to give a regex.based on that the program will automatically download files for me

Comment: Then why is this tagged with C# if you cannot write C# code to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think these aren't numbers but dates. So you want to take every date after `2015-08-20`.

You can use `String.Split` and `DateTime.TryParseExact` in this LINQ query:

```
string[] allowedFormats = { "yyyyMMdd" };
DateTime minDate = new DateTime(2015, 8, 20);

List<string> resultFilenames = fileNames
 .Select(fn => new { FileName = fn, DateString = fn.Split('_')[0].Trim() })
 .Select(x => new
 {
     x.FileName,
     DateOrNull = x.DateString.TryGetDateTime(null, allowedFormats)
 })
 .Where(x => x.DateOrNull.HasValue && x.DateOrNull.Value.Date > minDate)
 .Select(x => x.FileName)
 .ToList();
```

Used this extension to parse the string-token to a `DateTime?`:

```
public static DateTime? TryGetDateTime(this string item, DateTimeFormatInfo dfi, params string[] allowedFormats)
{
    if (dfi == null) dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;
    DateTime dt;
    bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(item, allowedFormats, dfi, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
    if (success) return dt;
    return null;
}
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your code file and the extension class must have added `using System.Globalization;` because of `DateTimeFormatInfo`. If you aren't familiar with extension methods have a loook [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Well if you really need a regular expression here it is.

```
$([1-9]\d{8,})|([3-9]\d{7})|(2[1-9]\d{6})|(20[2-9]\d{5})|(201[6-9]\d{4})|(2015[1-9]\d{3})|(201509\d\d)|(201508[3-9]\d)|(2015082[1-9])
```

This basically looks for 9 different cases at the beginning of the string by using `$` to anchor to the beginning and `|` to "or" the separate regular expressions together.  Below is a description of each case.

More than 8 digits where the first digit is greater than 0 (this one might not be needed assuming these are dates and you don't care about anything past the year 9999)

```
([1-9]\d{8,})
```

8 digits and first digit is greater than 3 (not needed if you don't care about anything past the year 2999)

```
([3-9]\d{7})
```

8 digits and the first digit is 2 and the second is greater than 0 (not needed if you don't care about anything past the year 2099)

```
(2[1-9]\d{6})
```

8 digits and the first 2 digits are 20 and the 3rd is greater than 1 (not needed if you don't care about anything past the year 2019)

```
(20[2-9]\d{5})
```

8 digits and the first 3 digits are 201 and the 4th is greater than 5 (not needed if you don't care about anything past the year 2015)

```
(201[6-9]\d{4})
```

8 digits and the first 4 digits are 2015 and the 5th is greater than 0

```
(2015[1-9]\d{3})
```

8 digits and the first 5 digits are 20150 and the 6th is greater than 8

```
(201509\d\d)
```

8 digits and the first 6 digits are 201508 and the 7th is greater than 2

```
(201508[3-9]\d)
```

8 digits and the first 7 digits are 2015082 and the 8th is greater than 0

```
(2015082[1-9])
```

It should be noted that this regular expression specifically works for the 20150820 date you are using as a minimum.  For any other date you'd have to create a different regular expression.  Also this does not validate that the number is an actual date.  Just a couple reason's why a parsing solution would be better.